# autossh - remote binding and closing the tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel

I'm trying to tunnel computer a to computer b (using autossh)

I want that port 8080 in `a.com` will be mapped to port 8080 in `b.com`

from computer **A**:

`autossh -M 0 -q -f -N -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 8081:localhost:22 root@b.com`

in computer **B**:

```
root@b.com:~# netstat -nal | grep 8081
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8081                :::*                    LISTEN
```

and from computer `B`:

`ssh -p 8081 root@127.0.0.1` works just fine (the tunnelling works)

the problem is **127.0.0.1:8081** I don't want it to be the local host but 0.0.0.0:8081 (like in ipv6).

Also, I would like to know how can I end the tunnel - I tried `ssh ~C -KL8081` but it didn't work:

```
Bad local forwarding specification '8081'
```

(I already killed the autossh in **A**).

Thanks!~

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer

1)

in server **B** we need to add `GatewayPorts yes`  to the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config:`

in computer a
`autossh -f -M 0  -N -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R  *:8081:localhost:22 root@b.com`

`killall autossh` terminates the autossh session